# How to use CSV Writer in rake task?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, rake-task

I am writing a rake task to output data from database and upload to ftp server.

The following seems to work:

```
require 'csv'

task export do
  CSV.open("temp_files/message_data.dat", "wb", '|') do |csv|
    csv << ['foo', 'bar', baz']      
  end
end
```

Now, to access a model, I seem to need

```
task :export => :environment do
```

This causes the code to fail:

```
rake aborted!
can't convert String into Integer
```

--trace shows:

```
/home/baller/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1335:in `initialize'
/home/baller/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1335:in `open'
```

How to use CSV Writer from a task and access a model?

Working in Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working. The call to CSV.open has changed:

```
CSV.open("temp_files/message_data.dat", "wb", :col_sep => '|')
```